# ¿Que diferencia hay entre "opereta" y "zarzuela"?

Tags: diferencias-entre-palabras, música

La [zarzuela](https://dle.rae.es/zarzuela) es

> 1. f. Obra dramática y musical de origen español en que alternativamente se habla y se canta.

y la [opereta](https://dle.rae.es/opereta?) es

> 1. f. Ópera cómica de asunto frívolo, con partes habladas y partes cantadas.

En principio parece que en ambas alternan partes habladas con partes cantadas y, según la definición, la única diferencia apreciable es que la opereta es *cómica* y la zarzuela es *dramática*. ¿Es esa la única diferencia entre ambas?

Answer (score 3):

> Si tuviéramos que explicar en una sola palabra cuál es la verdadera diferencia entre la ópera y la zarzuela lo tendríamos claro: la música. Mientras que en la ópera las acciones se desarrollan siempre con el acompañamiento de la música, la zarzuela ofrece una combinación de diferentes géneros como el teatro, el canto y el baile.

> Originaria de España, la zarzuela u opereta española es considera actualmente como un género menor que solo cuenta con representación en nuestro país y en otros lugares ubicados en Latinoamérica. Este estilo lírico teatral nació en 1657 y debe su nombre sobre todo al teatro de La Zarzuela, primer lugar donde comenzaron sus funciones

Fuente: [Ópera y Zarzuela, ¿qué diferencias hay entre ellas?](https://www.elcorteingles.es/entradas/blog/diferencias-entre-opera-y-zarzuela/)

> La zarzuela u opereta española es un género teatral cantado y hablado en prosa o en verso. La ópera generalmente es totalmente cantada

Fuente: [Diez diferencias entre la zarzuela y la ópera](http://www.tipografialamoderna.com/cultura/diez-diferencias-entre-la-zarzuela-y-la-opera/#:%7E:text=La%20zarzuela%20u%20opereta%20espa%C3%B1ola,los%20dedos%20de%20una%20mano.)

**Conclusiones**:
Hay un elemento de gran confusión y es que parece ser, leyendo esos enlaces, que la zarzuela es también conocida como *opereta española*. Para apreciar las diferencias (sutiles y técnicas en la mayoría de los casos) hay que entender bien el medio del que estamos hablando.

- A diferencia de la ópera, ‘singspiel’, opereta vienesa o francesa, la zarzuela esta cantada en castellano (y parece ser que por esos solo cuenta con representación en países de habla hispana, y no es todos).
- La zarzuela u opereta española es un género teatral cantado y hablado en prosa o en verso. La ópera generalmente es totalmente cantada.
- La mayor parte de las óperas representan tragedias con final más o menos trágico, con pocas excepciones. La mayor parte de las zarzuelas son comedias o de temática festiva humorística, también con pocas excepciones.
- La temática de las óperas iba dirigida a un público más refinado, nobleza y aristocracia, que asistían a la ópera con sus mejores galas. La temática de las zarzuelas iba dirigida a un público normal y corriente, que buscaba distraerse en el teatro

Comment: la diferencia entre la ópera y la zarzuela la veo bastante clara, lo que planteo es la diferencia entre **opereta** y **zarzuela**

Comment: Los artículos están ahí para citar las referencias y extraer los puntos clave de lo que define a la zarzuela en sí (no necesariamente frente a otras obras). La zarzuela es un género teatral cantado y hablado en prosa o en verso, popular en países de habla hispana y que trata de temas más mundanos que la ópera (por lo cual también se dirige a un público distinto). Es este el caso de la **opereta** también? La pregunta era `¿Es esa la única diferencia entre ambas?` y yo te doy una respuesta que dice que hay más diferencias, especificando las particularidades de la zarzuela.

Comment: Si lo he entendido bien, y obviando la parte sobre la opera, tu respuesta es **si**, si hay más diferencias entre opereta y zarzuela: la zarzuela esta **cantada en castellano** y la temática de las zarzuelas iba dirigida a un **público normal y corriente**, que buscaba distraerse en el teatro